# Handling file being downloaded from new browser window other than current browser window

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I am using Dotnetbrowser 1.11 and trying to download file on button click from a  website and have assigned downloadhandler to the browser. However allowdownload event does not fire after the button click. Have noticed that on manual button click a new browser window opens and save dialog pops up. Please assist how to handle such file downloads from new browser window other than currently loaded browser window.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download handling behavior depends on the contents of the currently loaded web page and can be different. Some websites intentionally open a popup to service a download request. Such popup ends up being blank.

The only way to workaround this behavior is to implement a custom popup handler that will handle these cases as expected for your application.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to get the window url from the PopupParams of PopupHandler, which i can use to download the file by adding download handler and loading this url in the browser.